# Which martial arts styles work best with social distancing?

Tags: training, health, etiquette, schools, covid-19

Yesterday, I saw a woman and a young boy sporting their TKD gear, shopping after class. I wondered what their school was doing to meet social distancing guidelines.

Wear a mask? Probably, not.

Stand six feet apart. Wash your hands. Don't touch people or your own face.

With Covid-19 cases increasing, I don't feel comfortable going to a gym or martial arts class yet.

**UPDATE on July 4th, Independence Day:** **The answers provided to this question helped with my internal dissonance regarding returning to martial arts training. I will wait.**

On Facebook, I found photos from two well-known, local jiu jitsu schools showing students and teachers training pre-Covid style.

The photos were posted in June, some a week before masks became mandatory in my city. I understand the need to avoid bankruptcy. I even understand the disagreement about wearing masks and social distancing. But how are they getting away with this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Beaches are closed in some areas. Restaurants and bars are heavily restricted and carefully monitored. Some have gone out of business because they can't operate effectively.

I feel sick to my stomach looking at these images. I know how much fun training is. Yet, if the health advisors are right, then training jiu jitsu -- without a mask is wrong.

The dissonance is back. Reckless disregard makes it hard for me to trust the leaders of these schools. I'm pulling my weight, wearing a mask for the last three months, to help fight Covid. And yes, my disagreement is my business. Their lives. Their risk.

Comment: I wonder if the boy was doing TKD at home over video when his mom decided to take him shopping? Most TKD schools are closed in the U.S. and probably much of the world right now.

Comment: Oh, and it's also possible the boy is doing TKD at home with his parents, siblings, or close friends through the lockdown.

Comment: And it's also possible, his mother didn't want to do extra laundry, so why bother changing out of your sweaty martial arts uniform before you go shopping. They were wearing masks, in case you're wondering.

Comment: And thank you, Steve, for framing the world in such a nice, safe, family-centered way.

Comment: Hi Macaco, I think target shooting is martial, but not a martial art.

Comment: By the way, Macaco, who is Pat?

Comment: How about naginata?

Comment: @thatgirlisfunny It's a matter of some dispute as to how guns fit into martial arts. I have friends who actively train for competitions involving things like shooting while diving for cover, or other physical challenges. As regards "pat", I was using the adjectival form, the meaning of which can range from "apt" to "contrived" depending on context.

Comment: @Huw Thanks, I'll google naginata.

Answer (score 4):

In the era of COVID-19, partner training is a bad idea. You do not want to spend extended periods of time breathing heavily in the same space, and especially not indoors. Grappling is particularly risky.

Many martial arts already include social-distancing-ready methods in their standard training that can fill your social-distancing training hours. Many of these methods are not suitable for partner training, so now is the ideal time to get full use of them. They do not substitute for the fighting skills you acquire sparring and partner training, but those are not available right now.

I will avoid evaluating styles and instead point out elements that can/should be practiced with social distancing. Lots of styles have these elements, so I will point out a few examples and leave evaluation to you.

### Forms

Forms training is the foundation of many martial arts body development. Forms usually combine elements of speed, balance, leg strength and flexibility, coordination, mental focus, and prototypes of martial techniques together in one package. Styles using forms include kung fu (in all its flavors), karate, and tae kwon do.

Depending on your social distancing risk tolerance, you may be comfortable having a masked instructor stop you periodically and make physically adjust your body. The time they need to be near you is short and they can otherwise be at a distance. Otherwise, the instructor can demonstrate at a distance and provide feedback. Outdoor forms practice would be preferable to indoor.

The general problem with forms is that styles can have them without being able to fight. But you should be able to imagine that someone able to fight can give you sequences of movements to work on, and those sequences can be called forms.

### Basics - Footwork as an example

Most people are not willing to invest the time in learning "basics" that they could because sparring and other exercises are more fun. Now is the perfect time to focus basics you can practice alone because your partners are not available. This analysis is based on my study of bagua, but I expect you will find it applies to boxing, kickboxing, MMA, etc.

Let's assume your style has a fighting stance that you use. Enter your fighting stance, then take a step forward.

- [Are you immediately in your fighting stance again? Or is your spacing off?](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/q/9900/5961)
- Are you immediately balanced, or do you need a moment to regain your balance?
- Are you on balance as you move? If someone were to grab your belt (something around your waist) and then you step, would you be leaning to move forward?
- Do your legs drive your movement when you step? Or do you fall into your step?
- Is your step fast, or is this a great time for a sparring partner to sweep your feet?
- Now that you have tried to fix several different things, are the earlier ones still fixed?

OK, so now that you have fixed all of these things, you can add steps in other directions. You probably at least want to also step angled to the left, step angled to the right, and backwards possibly also to the side. Presumably you started facing an opponent, so as you move to the side angles, you will want to turn towards your opponent.

- Check all of the above items again for each direction
- Now that you are turning as you are stepping, are you leaning as if banking into a turn on a bicycle? Do not lean because this puts you off balance.

Now you can step in multiple directions.

- Can you react from your fighting stance to move in each direction equally well? If not, why is this your fighting stance?
- Can you move in any direction at reflex fighting speed, or do you stop to think about it?
- What happens when you practice stepping in a field where the ground is not perfectly flat? Are you tripping over the little divots animals have dug?

You can practice all the footwork alone, although it can be helpful to have partners provide moving resistance or other feedback. It takes a surprisingly long time to learn footwork, and honestly the training can become a slog, but really at some point the footwork becomes advanced and not basic.

We have not even started on the hands yet, but this is enough.

Comment: Reading through your answer helped me to give up my "waiting to go back" position and shift over to "deciding to stay home". I haven't organized my at-home workouts to be effective. But I might as well get on with it because with cases increasing, Covid is winning. Time to accept defeat (no partner training) and adapt to the new normal. After four months of restrictions, I'm feeling very sad about the need for social distancing.

Comment: @thatgirlisfunny If you have kids at home, or just family members, have them throw tennis balls at you while you stand in front of a wall and dodge them with slips and ducks and footwork. This is what I have been doing for the last 3 days with my roommate. But he is charging me $5 per 30 min.

Comment: Lol! That could get out of hand pretty quickly. Your roommate is smart. Get that beer money!

Answer (score 3):

The only martial arts training that makes sense if social distancing is a priority is [getting strong and fit in your home gym](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/a/1756/347). Make of your body the strongest, fittest, fastest, most agile, flexible, and powerful version of itself it can be. When we have coronavirus treatments and vaccines so we can do contact training again, do that.

Comment: Hi Dave, I agree with you about the home gym. At least that's something I have control over.

Answer (score 3):

> Which martial arts styles work best with **social distancing**?

#### I will talk about *the striking arts* (e.g., boxing, kickboxing, taekwondo, karate, etc.).

**Working with non-humans:**

Heavy bags are your best option now (from your YouTube channel, it seems you have some decent experience in striking). Most gyms where I am have opened with the policy that students will book sessions in advance to come in and work on the bags (heavy bags, speed bags, double-end bags, bobs, and other stationary striking dummies). This makes sense because each student is given a bucket with some cleaning agents and towels to wipe off the bags before and after use.

Some gyms have done an excellent job of creating "work pods" — square shaped designated working spaces marked with colored tapes around heavy bags. There is decent amount of space to work around a bag. Depending on your gym, you *can* book your session in splits; for example, a 30-30-30 split, where you work on a specific "working pod" for 30 minutes before moving on to a different one. Note that there are other students who are also working on the bags. So, the designated working areas ensure that everyone follows "social distancing" guidelines, and that all students have a safe working environment.

**Working with humans:**

This is a little complicated. In my region, some gyms have started classes (boxing/kickboxing). Again, the number of students per session/class has been reduced, and each student has their own "work pod" for that class. The classes mostly include

- some high intensity cardio and stretching,
- fast paced combo work (which the instructor calls out),
- fight breakdown on a projector once a week (this is new, never done before) where the instructor explains techniques and strategies from classic fights,
- and finally, some pad work only for advanced level students (consider them regulars, have been coming to the gym for a long time, are matured enough to understand the well-being of others).

But this is very rare. In my region, there has been very few COVID19 cases so far, and gyms are strictly following rules and regulations outlined by the local government. These policies are not recommended for all places.

> Wear a mask? Probably, not.

It *is* irritating to do martial arts wearing a mask at a high pace. However, I have seen students wearing masks made of very thin and light material in the gym. I will say this though, with the cloth mask on, you can still shadowbox at 100%, maybe for fewer rounds. And if you are working with a partner, having the mask on is a good idea.

If you know and have people you trust to work with, people who take precautions with utmost care, you can do some [long distance pad work with **foam pool noodles**](https://youtu.be/LI9CpkbHqpM?t=32). But really, this is up to you; you will have to make that decision along with your peers. Anyways, note that in the video, they are standing quite close to each other, and Shane is  not holding the noodles at the end. If you hold the noodles at the end, you can increase the distance between you and your partner. Also, you can use longer noodles.

[image]

For kicking, you can use the taekwondo kick pads. These should allow you to have some space between you and your partner.

[image] [image]

Comment: Thanks, Roundhouse. This answer is really helpful. Gyms are allowed to open with full capacity where I live, even though our Covid cases are rapidly increasing. I would definitely wear a mask, if I trained at a local school. But, I worry about two things. Masks slip off and people are barefoot on the mats. Mats aren't cleaned between classes. I guess I'm just not ready to return yet. So, home gym for me. The foam noodle workout looks fun!

Comment: You are right, if you think that somehow your gym may be compromised, it is better to not go for now. This is something I have noticed in Martial Arts gyms - they don't seem to put in much effort in cleaning the floors/mats between sessions. In contrast, my local weight-room gyms always clean the working pods whenever someone finishes working out (this is in addition to the member cleaning that area themself). But one BJJ training center in my region have 30 min gaps between the classes, and some students will stay back and clean the mats. Sadly, they don't do this in my gym.

Answer (score 1):

The two sports which come to mind are [Chinese Tai Chi](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GvQUttWLVWc) and [Brazilian Capoeira](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sb6CimOoAVE).

Both of them are **non contact** sports. I think first one is like a gymnastics and second one is like a dance.

But they still widely considered by me as a form of martial art.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Unfortunately, there are multiple problems with this answer. First, the video you have linked for taiji (tai chi) is not taiji but a form of qi gong. While taiji has qi gong, this qi gong is not taiji. Second, taiji is definitely not what I would call gymnastic. Third, taiji can defiitely be contact.

Comment: Thanks. You’re right I don’t know much about either sport. Comparing taiji to gymnastics is likely comparing fencing with tennis, same moves different purpose. Qigong looks nice, something new I learn.

Comment: Honestly, doing a Capoeira *roda* is probably a bad idea too. There's still a lot of close contact (and people will make contact in some fights, depending on the school's philosophy), not to mention that the singing is a major part of the style, and we all know how far singing projects spittle. It is one that's not bad to practice solo, of course.

Comment: Thanks. I know what you mean about spittle, I remember having competitions about it growing up. Capoeira is unlike any other sports I've seen so I've assumed its technique was more Art than Martial, but the dancing part may be like a warm up.